# Write textBox value in existing JSON file using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

Please help me to write textbox value / data into existing JSON file. I have tried with code below but unable with this.  I am able to write in "textarea" but not in existing JSON file please let me know how to refer existing JSON file here and write data on that file.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []).controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.person = {};
    $scope.getJSON = function () {
        console.log("Creating a JSON");
        $scope.jsonString = angular.toJson($scope.person, true);       
    };
});
```

My JSON file existing in dir: `DataBase/DataBase.json`

Answer (score 0):

Most browsers don't allow javascript to access file system, most probably you would not be able to do this. I could suggest you to send your `json` data to a backend and rewrite file there.

Comment: Could you please give me a small demo with that I can understand more clearly how can I send data to  backend and rewrite it.

Comment: It depends on the backend that will handle your application.

Comment: To save textbox data I m using JSON file so here JSON is my backend.

Comment: Well, I'll try to explain one more time. `json` file is just your data, not a `backend`. In order to update your data, you should update this file. Javascript can't write to a file unless you're making a post back to a server which can then do the update to your `json` file.

Comment: Yeah I can understand that JSON is only a file that's why I am asking how to write in it.

Comment: So, what "backend application" will handle your angular app? Php, ruby, node?

Comment: My backend application is node.

Comment: Ok, then you have to create a route for your application which will handle a request from your angular app. This route should receive json data as a request parameter and save it to the file. Here is described how you can write files n nodejs: https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/file-system/how-to-write-files-in-nodejs

Answer (score 0):

Keep your json file inside mongodb or sqlite,then you can do all curd operation in the Json data